# Launching NUnit from Visual Studio can't load nunit.uikit.XmlSerializers

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, nunit

I have set my Visual Studio to start Nunit as an external program to run all the tests written in a module.

It gives me this error: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.uikit.XmlSerializers, Version=2.5.0.9122, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77

but if I run it from command-line:
nunit.exe Tests.dll

it launches just fine. I can also open up the GUI and then point it to the DLL and it works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This exception is an internal exception NUnit is throwing, I have my debugger to break on exceptions when they are thrown so it was stopping :)